# I want to show data from room database in recycler view using pager

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-room, android-paging-3, rx-java3

Room Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM any_table")
List<Any> getAllAny();
```

I want to use Pager3 with Rx Java to show the data in recyclerview because loading all data at once lags UI.

If possible change the return type of query to flowable or something either

```
Flowable<List<Any>> getAllNotes();
PagingSource<Integer, Any> getAllNotes();
Flowable<PagingData<Note>> getAllNotes();
```

How can i achieve this?